# source ~/.cshrccommand error source not found in freeBSD 11?

Tags: freebsd

```
source ~/.cshrc
```

produces this error:

> -sh: source: not found

in freeBSD 11. It works for version 10.

What is the equivalent in 11?

Answer (score 1):

`source` is a built-in command for [tsch(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=csh) (aka `csh`).

The error message implies that you are attempting to interpret the file using [sh(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh).

In `sh` you would use `.` to include another source file.

This is the same in both 10 and 11, maybe your shell is set up differently now.